# MS Access: Playing with dates

Tags: sql, string, date, ms-access, type-conversion

I was asked to make a query for "last month" sales. So I figured out that given today's date, we only need to substract 1 to the current month:

```
Where DateAdd("m", -1, Date()
```

However, this function (of course) does not affect the day. Since "last month" sales should include every sale from the starting of the month up to the end. But hey, I thought, we can query all sales that were made in the previous month, like this:

```
Where DatePart("m", <Table.field>) = DatePart("m", DateAdd("m", -1, Date())) And
DatePart("yyyy", <Table.field>) = DatePart("yyyy", Date())
```

Thing is that such comparison still wants the days to match. Thus, my current frame of mind is to find a way to part the date into strings for day, month, and year, and then convert them back to a real date, but it seems like I'm working against MS Access. Perhaps there is an easier way to accomplish this. What do you think? Thanks!

Comment: So you need Year and Month. Perhaps: `Format(field, "yyyymm") = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date()), "yyyymm")`.

Comment: Looks promising. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use *DateDiff*:

```
Where DateDiff("m", [YourDateField], Date()) = 1
```